# How to prevent duplicated resource ID in different plugins?

Tags: c++, mfc, resources

In MFC C++, When we add a new resourcein a EXE, says string, it will generate an ID automatically:

```
#define ID_SHOW_OUTPUT                 10313
```

When it has a plugin(DLL) which has the similar ID, it will cause undefined behavior after trigerred.

To play safe, I tried to define the my own private ID:

```
#define ID_SHOW_OUTPUT          (WM_APP+6)
```

However, I will have a lot of work if there are hundreds of resources in the EXE and DLL.

I'm not sure there is a better solution and prevention on duplicated resource ID across executables???

Comment: What problems are you having?  Having duplicate resource IDs in different modules is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check [this add-in](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/resorg.aspx). It gives you a higher control over resource ids.
- As Luke commented, there should not be problems using DLLs with duplicte resource ids. Only one resource module is active at a time using [AfxSetResourceHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ws31ff(VS.80).aspx)
- Setting Command IDs to arbitrary `UINT` values (In your question you assigned `WM_APP + 6` to a command ID) is not safe since these values are interpreted by MFC in many places. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572364/mfc-resource-h-command-message-ids) StackOverflow question for more details.

Comment: The ResOrg recommended is indeed a cool tool. It will be perfect if it is able to load multiple Resource.h, from exe and dlls within the same process... Do you have seen this kind of tool?