# Resource conflict on ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an EXE class which contains a button resource with ID `EXE_BUTTON_RESOURCE`

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(EXE_BUTTON_RESOURCE, OnUpdateExeButtonResource)

void EXE::OnUpdateExeButtonResource(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
        pCmdUI->Enable(exe_flag);

}
```

This EXE application will load another DLL class.

DLL class is having a menu item resource with ID `DLL_MENU_RESOURCE`.

Unfortunately, `EXE_BUTTON_RESOURCE` and `DLL_MENU_RESOURCE` is having the same resource ID. To avoid them have conflict ID is pretty difficult, as they are two separate projects.

Whenever exe_flag, which is the member for EXE turn to false, this will affect menu in DLL too. Clicking on `DLL_MENU_RESOURCE` menu will have no effect at all.

How can I avoid this trap? Having manual inspection on their resource.h files is not an option for me, as they are 2 separate projects, managed by 2 separate teams.

Once, I thought it might be resource conflicting problem. Hence, in DLL code which show the right clicked menu, I have the following code the load DLL resource, and restore back EXE resource when done.

```
void DLL::OnContextMenu(CWnd* pWnd, CPoint point) 
{
    RestoreDLLState ext;
        ...
}
```

RestoreDLLState will load global DLL resource, and load back its original resource once done.

```
RestoreDLLState::RestoreDLLState()
{
    m_hInstOld = AfxGetResourceHandle();
    AfxSetResourceHandle(g_hDLLResource);
}

RestoreDLLState::~RestoreDLLState()
{
    AfxSetResourceHandle(m_hInstOld);
}
```

That doesn't work. My guess is that, the action to enable/disable resource with particular ID, will propagate from EXE till DLL, regardless what is the default resource being loaded currently.

To be honest, I had posted the similar question to [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3621822/Re-Resource-conflict-on-ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI.aspx) and [microsoft.public.vc.mfc](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/browse_thread/thread/5728eff80f80f589#), but didn't get much useful comment out from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this for a cool tool:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/resorg.aspx-

Another useful post:
[MFC resource.h command/message IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572364/mfc-resource-h-command-message-ids)

Comment: I try to have opinion from the author of resorg. Seem like avoiding conflict of ID is the best way. (Perhaps the only way?)